# Karma test fail with module config $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I meet problem when run karma to test controller in angularjs 1.5. Everything that ok, but when I inject `ui-router` to my module, it will be broken. 
I create module in file **buffalo.template.module.js** as below

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('Buffalo.template', [])
    .config(['$stateProvider', routeConfig]);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('crawler_template', {
        url: '/crawler-template',
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/buffalo/src/template/buffalo.template.html',
        title: 'Crawler Template',
        controller: "BuffaloTemplateController",
        controllerAs: "tempCtrl",
        sidebarMeta: {
          icon: 'ion-ios-paper-outline',
          order: 1
        }
      });
  }

})();
```

And controller in file **BuffaloTemplateController.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Buffalo.template')
    .controller('BuffaloTemplateController', buffaloTemplateController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function buffaloTemplateController() {
    var ctrler = this;

    ctrler.name = 'test';
    ctrler.base_url = undefined;
    ctrler.list_urls = [undefined];

    ctrler.addUrlLink = function () {
      ctrler.list_urls.push(undefined);
    };

    ctrler.generate = function () {
      console.log(ctrler.name);
      console.log(ctrler.base_url);
    };

  }
})();
```

And my test in file **BuffaloTemplateSpec.js**

```
describe('Buffalo Template Module', function() {

    describe('Controller', function() {

        var controller;

        beforeEach(function() {

        module('Buffalo.template');

        inject(function($controller) {
            controller = $controller('BuffaloTemplateController');
        })
      });

        it('should initialize the title in the scope', function() {
         console.log(controller);
    });

    });

});
```

When karma run my tests, has fail message

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Buffalo Template Module Controller should initialize the title in the scope FAILED
    forEach@/home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
    loadModules@/home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4601:12
    createInjector@/home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4523:30
    workFn@/home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3074:60
    inject@/home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3054:46
    unit/BuffaloTemplateSpec.js:11:12
    loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
    /home/quangtm-s3/workspaces/personal/rtm/owl/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4641:53
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.04 secs / 0.008 secs)
```

But when I comment module config, karma run tests successfully. What wrong with my situation. How can I tests my controller, module. Thanks advance.

Comment: Where are you injecting ui-router into the unit test? I don't see it there. Also, you'll need to add the module for the parent state of this state.

Comment: Oh, thank for your reminding. I forgot inject module `ui-router` and include file `angular-ui-router.js` in karma config file. I fixed this case.